# How to make specflow scenarios visible to others without using visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, specflow

I was wondering if there is a way to make visible to other peers the scenarios we have in our feature files without them using visual studio. For example :does specflow has a library or an option that can generate a document for us with a list of all the scenarios. The goal is to have some type of documentation  other teams can review  and see all the  scenarios we have in our features. We don't want then to install and setup visual studio. We also don't want them to have access to the entire program.

Comment: This illustrates why I don't like SpecFlow. Supposedly it allows writing tests using plain language that non-technical users can understand. In the real world only developers have the tools and the ability to read and write the tests. Developers end up reading and writing the tests. Those tests are harder to write and maintain because of the overhead of making them accessible to non-technical users, but in the end those non-technical users don't look at the tests.

Comment: Why not just share the .feature files?

Comment: @ScottHannen If you need to be a techie to understand your feature files, then I suspect you are using Specflow incorrectly.   The feature files are meant to be written by a BA, in BA style language.  IME devs write dev style tests, which really should be integration test not Specflow tests.

Comment: Specflow (that is, Cucumber) is trivial to parse if all you're doing is hunting for scenarios (grep for "Scenario:"). That's assuming you need to parse it at all, since, per Neil, the feature files *should* be human readable, without any need for opening an IDE. That's sort of the entire point. And Scott's experience notwithstanding, I've had success with tests being written and *debugged* by people who were not developers, and had no desire to become developers. You can be "technical" even if you don't program (or *think* you're not programming...)

Comment: I've no doubt that it works for many. My thought is that if non-technical people are not looking at them then they're not much good. If non-technical people are writing them or getting some real value from them, awesome.

Comment: Does the answer and the comment above can help you?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same approach as part of the build pipeline.

We had a PowerShell script that converted `*.feature` files to markdown files. (feature files are actually just text files so you can just rename them)

And then it converted `*.md` files to pdf files using [md-to-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-to-pdf)

So as a result of each of your CI build you will have an archive with `*.pdf` files that you can share.